# why wget change file type?

Tags: linux, wget, tar

I am downloading a tar.gz file using this command:

```
wget -c http://example.com/example.tar.gz
```

When download complete,check file type:

```
file example.tar.gz
```

The output is:**HTML document text**.Unpack file:

```
tar -zxvf example.tar.gz
```

The output:

```
gzip: example.tar.gz: not in gzip format
```

Why would this happen? What should I do to make it right? I am absolutely sure it is a tar.gz file because if U change the way I download it, I can successfully unpack it. This command makes it work:

```
curl -O http://example.com/example.tar.gz
```

Comment: Look at the file in a text editor to see if its an error messages returned from the server, such as a 404 page.

Comment: Probably would have taken you less time to look inside the file with `less` than type out this question. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` doesn't change the file format. http://example.com/example.tar.gz, despite what it's name may suggest, isn't a tar.gz archive, but just a plain old HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

`wget` doesn't change the file type but what you got as a response for your request was not what you expected.  You expected a tar archive but got an HTML file.  `wget` just stores what it got under the name you specified.

Have a look at the contents of HTML file you got.  It probably tells you what error has happened (that's the typical case why you get an HTML file instead of what you expected).